# How to set port in GOlang when starting net/http server with variable

Tags: go

I am attempting to try a small project in Go to learn it. I am trying to use the standard library as much as possible. While learning how to read environment variables, I decided to change my API to read the port from the ENV variable. I am getting the ENV variable correctly, but when I start the application it errors. If I hardcode the port in the script directly it works fine, but if I try to use the variable it errors. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? I have searched around but unsure what exactly I'm looking for to find an answer to this question. Thanks for your help.

```
    http.HandleFunc("/", controllers.HealthController)
    appPort := ":" + os.Getenv("APP_PORT")
    fmt.Println(appPort) // This prints ":9001"
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":9001", // << But if I use appPort here it doesn't work, but if I hardcode it like this it works.
    }
    log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
```

This is the error:

```
unknown port30:43 listen tcp: address tcp/9001
```

EDIT:

So I tried to do this:

```
port := ":9001"
```

And then pass that variable in and it works fine. So now my assumption is that for some reason my string concat or ENV variable is incorrect. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try printing with `fmt.Printf("Port: %q\n", appPort);` - that prints appPort as a Go string in source code, making it easier to identify things like control/non-ascii characters or trailing spaces. I'm not able to make sense of your error message though. I think you failed to copy some spaces. Also, what are you passing in environment variable `APP_PORT~ ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt That was it! I ran what you said and it returned: `Port: ":9001\r"` so I had a carriage return in my .ENV file. I am carrying over too much from Node I think. My startup script looks like: `env $(cat ./.env | xargs) go run main.go` and `.env` is just `APP_PORT=9001`. I assume I can probably do this an easier way. Thanks for your help!